# Prevent date overlap postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, overlap

Is there a way to add a constraint to a postgresql table to prevent dates overlapping? For example, I have a table called `workouts` that has date columns `week_start`, `week_end`. I want to make sure that none of the week_start - week_end ranges overlaps with any existing ranges. HOWEVER, the end date of `week_start` can overlap with the start date of `week_end`.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are using week numbers? If so, there can be no overlap between dates of weeks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION), using the [overlap operator (`&&`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) for the [`daterange` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html):

```
CREATE TABLE workouts (
  week_start DATE,
  week_end DATE,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (daterange(week_start, week_end) WITH &&)
)
```

Comment: Thanks - to confirm, would this allow overlap of the end of week_start with the beginning of week_end? For example, 6/1 - 6/3 and 6/3 - 6/4 should be allowed.

Comment: @user1547174: Yes, the `daterange()` function includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound.

Comment: Gotcha - I tried the command `alter table workouts add constraint EXCLUDE USING gist (daterange(week_start, week_end) WITH &&);` but I'm getting `ERROR: syntax error at or near "USING"`... Could you please let me know what the syntax error might be?

Comment: @user1547174: You need to either give the constraint a name (`ADD CONSTRAINT c EXCLUDE ...`) or drop the `CONSTRAINT` keyword altogether (`ADD EXCLUDE ...`)

Comment: Will this increase the chance of deadlocks?

Comment: @Adzz: Actually, yes, it looks like there's a [known issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1518421113328-0.post%40n3.nabble.com#5e8685b9e397258362566cd59c907a6e) which causes simultaneous overlapping inserts to throw deadlock errors instead of constraint violation errors. This shouldn't really matter for most use cases - it was going to fail anyway, just with a different error message - but it could be a real problem if you need high throughput and you expect a lot of violations (as there is some delay before the deadlock detection kicks in).

Comment: Ah I think this is what was biting me when running concurrent integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `EXCLUDE` table constraint to your table definition and then work with ranges to detect overlaps. This would work really nice if you can change your table definition to turn columns `week_start` and `week_end` into a single range, say `weeks`.

```
CREATE TABLE workouts (
  ...
  weeks   intrange
  EXCLUDE USING gist (weeks WITH &&)
);
```